# heroku mysqltopostgres installation error

Tags: mysql, heroku

I am trying to deploy my php app that uses mysql db to heroku.
I followed instructions here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

The `sudo gem install mysqltopostgres-0.3.0.gem` command executed without errors:

> gem build mysqltopostgres.gemspec
>
> Successfully built RubyGem
>
> Name: mysqltopostgres
>
> Version: 0.3.0
>
> File: mysqltopostgres-0.3.0.gem

but when I try to execute the `mysqltopostgres` command, the following errors occur

> mysqltopostgres /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in
>   'block in setup': You have already activated test-unit 2.5.5, but your
>   Gemfile requires test-unit 3.2.1. Prepending 'bundle exec' to your
>   command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in 'setup'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:92:in 'setup'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:8:in ''
>     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   'require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   'require'     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysqltopostgres-0.3.0/bin/mysqltopostgres:5:in
>   ''    from /usr/local/bin/mysqltopostgres:22:in 'load'
>     from /usr/local/bin/mysqltopostgres:22:in ''

I then tried to prepend bundle exec:

> bundle exec mysqltopostgres
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in 'find_spec_for_exe':
>   can't find gem mysqltopostgres (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
>     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in
>   'activate_bin_path'   from /usr/local/bin/mysqltopostgres:22:in
>   ''

Has anyone ever come across these errors?
And I am new to Heroku, and I was building my app on my local apache and now I want to deploy it to heroku.

Comment: any luck? I'm encountering this issue as well.

Comment: @yin03 not yet... I emailed heroku devs and they said I should open an issue here - https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres/ Havent had time to do that yet

Comment: @yin03 someone replied on this issue on github. Quote: Don't run the command in the "mysql2postgres/" directory, where you've built mysql2postgres. Run it outside, where your configuration yaml file is located.
Can you try and see if it works? I am not going near my pc for another 2 weeks, cant check